# Patch Encoder for ViT implementation in Python

Tags: python, transformer-model

I am learning about the visual transformers from this [link](https://analyticsindiamag.com/hands-on-guide-to-using-vision-transformer-for-image-classification/). I couldn't understand the implementation **Step 2.3: Patch encoder** in that which is:

```
    def __init__(self, num_patches, projection_dim):
        super(PatchEncoder, self).__init__()
        self.num_patches = num_patches
        self.projection = layers.Dense(units=projection_dim)
        self.position_embedding = layers.Embedding(
            input_dim=num_patches, output_dim=projection_dim
        )
 
    def call(self, patch):
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=self.num_patches, delta=1)
        encoded = self.projection(patch) + self.position_embedding(positions)
        return encoded
```

Anyone please help me to understand what exactly this function is doing

Answer (score 0):

`PatchEncoder` takes a flattened patch as input, linearly projects it to the desired input dimension (which is the `projection_dim`), and adds positional embedding to each patch.

We will use cifar10 as an example.
The original image [None, 32, 32, 3] is resized to [None, 72, 72, 3] by `data_augmentation`.
In `Patches`, resized images are divided by patch size 6, so the flattened patches are [None, 12, 12, 108].
Finally, reshape is performed, so the input to `PatchEncoder` will be [None, 144, 108].

In `PatchEncoder`, the Dense layer is applied first and projected to the `projection_dim` dimension, resulting in [None, 144, 64].
`position_embedding` (defined as layers.Embedding) is the process of converting the sequential numbers of the patches generated by tf.range into a vector of projection_dim dimensions, which are added to projected patches, and the final output `encoded` is [ None, 144, 64].

Note: None represents an arbitrary batch size.

I hope this helps in understanding.